# jQuery select2 More than one of the same type in mulitple select

Tags: jquery, html

I am using select2 (which can be found [here](https://select2.org/)), and I want to have a multiple select box. To do this, `<select multiple></select>` is used. But the problem with this is that you cannot have more than one of the same option. For example:

```
<select multiple>
    <option>First Option</option>
    <option>Second Option</option>
    <option>Third Option</option>
</select>
```

And I want to have 2 of the `Second Option`'s selected. How do I do this? Also, how would I get the value of this `<select multiple>`?

Note: I am not able to use more than one `<select>`

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear what you ask.
Here are my variants:

**If you want to have one multiple select with the same option (if you choose one, it appears in selected, but also stays in List - you described this requirement in comment.**

I guess it is not possible simple with select2. You have to look for another control.

**If you want to have two multiple selects with the same options.**

You have to add some classes to your original select.
And then do `$('.my-select1').select2();` and `do $('.my-select2').select2();`

In this case you would be able to select values using selector `.my-select1` and `.my-select2`.

See https://jsfiddle.net/hfmeey2z/1/ as example of two multiple selects with the same values.

**If you want to have one multiple select with two options with the same Name.**
You have to use different `"value"` attribute for each option.

```
 <option value="JAN">January</option>
 <option value="JAN2">January</option>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hfmeey2z/2/

Comment: I do not want more than one normal `<select>`, I want just one `<select multiple>` but I want to be able to have more than one type of option selected inside that `<select multiple>`.

Comment: I do not get you. You need two multisselects on one page? Or you want one multiselect with two equal options?

Comment: When you have a `<select multiple>`, you can have multiple values inside the box. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/evF9I But with the `<select multiple>` it does not allow you to have more than one option, for example `Sheridan`. You cannot have it twice. How would I allow it to have more than one?

Comment: See my fiddler example. But it has two different selects, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yeah that's 2 different `<select>`s, I want one `<select>` but with 2 values inside that are the same. In your example, I would want April, and April again both in the same `<select>`

Comment: What I want is like a menu at a fast food place. The menu is the same, with 1 type of each option, but I want to order 2x burgers. I want 2 of the same option. Is this not possible?

Comment: This is not how multiselect works I guess you should look for another control.